# How to display a list in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

Trying to print the song stings in a list box. I tried just adding them as items, but that just prints windowsform1.cs. Do I have to convert the items, or is their a function i need for the listbox to print strings and an int.

```
private string title;
private string album, title, artist, genre;
private int length;

private void List_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MDB.listAllSongs(listBox1.Items);

}

public void listAllSongs(IList list)
{
    List<Song> allSongs = new List<Song>();
    foreach (Album album in albums)
    {
        album.listSongs(allSongs);
    }

    foreach (Song song in allSongs)
    {
        list.Add(song.ToString());
    }
}

public void listSongs(List<Song> list)
{
    foreach (Song song in songs)
    {
        list.Add(song);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the toString() method in the Song class, to return the title of your song:

```
public string toString()
{
    return title;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i have done this, but it is still coming up with the same thing